# Math and SI formatting buttons

Tags: discussion, mathjax

After having to add dollar signs and format SI  units countless times in the review section, I finally got fed up and wrote a script.{*}

It basically adds buttons to enclose the selected text in dollar symbols and `\mathrm` SI unit formatting.

[Here's the userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/3373/mathjax-buttons). Installation instructions are there.

<sup>*With some urging from chem.SE.people, otherwise it was going to be indefinitely in my todo list :P</sup>

Comment: Hey, I just installed this (using Tampermonkey), but now *all* my editor buttons are gone! Any idea what's going on here? Is this thing still working, or has it become outdated?

Comment: @Danu works for me,  but I used to use Chrome's in built userscript functionality which is now disabled for Windows. I'll have a look when I get the time.

Comment: tampermonkey seemed to be OK with it and indicates it's running... Hope you manage to find out what's going on (assuming I didn't mess up?!)

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-to-write-physical-units

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment (literally, I can't post comments) but I can say that although it's a bit limited in features, it's definitely a step forward for the editor!

In contrast, the link you provided has dead download sub-links :(

Comment: You can comment here :) . What other features would you like? Note that it has keyboard shortcuts (which ought to be more used than the buttons anyway)--so it's reasonably quick and easy to use. I also fixed the sublinks, thanks for that (had done a file rename, forgot about it :P )

Comment: @Manishearth, Sorry about that, I never received a notification on your comment but I'll try it and report back here :)

Comment: @Manishearth, How about the following: 1. A choice between "\mathbf and \vec", maybe "\text or \mathrm" for constants, too. If it's _easily_ doable in JS, I'd suggest this too 2. A button to search the selected text and replace brackets (,),[&] to \right( , \left] , ... etc. What do you think?

Comment: Not really easily doable as a choice, since I'd have to add some configuration. I _am_ planning on making it customizable, so I'll let you know--but that's far off. Actually I'll think about this for a while--maybe I can add some rudimentary customizeability.

Comment: @Manishearth, fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

### Note to users who installed it before 5/5/12 (3:51 PM UTC):

The script no longer needs to be updated (most updates include the addition of more sites/buttons and tweaks like tooltips). It auto-fetches the updates now.

I suggest you uninstall/reinstall it to run this one-time update

How to uninstall:

- Chrome: Settings>Tools>Extensions. Find the script and delete it
- Firefox: Open the GM settings and remove the script

Then re-install normally ([click here](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/MathJaxButtons.user.js))